# How to post a Utest project?

Tags: android, user-acceptance-testing

We have an android app that we have to do a little bit of usability testing/beta testing.All I have found about Utest.com is you can sign up and work on projects, but I was unable to find how to post projects in Utest and how to get people to do usability testing.

I am fine with other paid options as well, but if it is free or something like usabilityhub where we can do testing and then earn points to exchange for credit, then I am fine.

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask, if not please point me to the right place.

Comment: Have you tried asking at the [Utest forums](http://forums.utest.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

uTest was rebranded a while ago as Applause, but back when it was uTest I considered hiring them. I think I filled something out online and then a sales engineer followed up with a call. It's not free. When I chatted with them they charged per "test cycle" and recommended 3 cycles for our app. The test cycle was flat rate plus a monthly charge to use their platform.

To get a better idea I'd fill out the price estimator here: http://www.applause.com/pricing-estimator. My guess is they will follow up with you once you do that. If all else fails fill out the contact form: http://www.applause.com/contact-us.

There are other crowd sourced testing services like Applause that allow you to choose what type of testing you'd like to do and spread the work across numerous users with different devices. Depending on your goals this might be good or bad. Other options could include dog fooding your app or hiring an individual usability tester.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I work at Applause as the Director of Community (uTest).*

We offer some free services but from your brief description it sounds like you're looking for some of our paid services. As Chris mentioned, you can fill out a Pricing Request and/or Contact Us but I'm happy to help if you want to email me directly at msolar@applause.com.

In the meantime you might find this page on our Mobile Beta Management interesting; http://www.applause.com/mobile-beta-management

Hope that helps.

Matt